# CASE with IS NULL not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I want to give column some value if the value is `NULL` I tried like below

```
insert into inward_doc_tracking_trl 
    (Mkey,Entry_Sr_No,N_UserMkey,N_Department,CStatus_Flag,Remarks,     
    CUser_Id,
    U_Datetime,NStatus_Flag,Delete_Flag, 
    CDept_Id,
    Ref_Mkey,No_Of_Days,Approved_Amount,Chq_No,Chq_dated,Chq_Bank,Chq_Amount,
    Vendor_MKey,Vendor_Comp_Mkey,Project_Mkey,Program_mkey,Payment_MKey,Due_Date,Updated_Remarks,Updated_Bill_no,
    Updated_Bill_Date,Updated_Bill_Amt,Party_Name,Acc_mkey,
    TotalDeductions,Broker_Mkey,Customer_Mkey,Payable_Amt,Balance_Amt)

     values (@inv_trl_mkey,@entry_sr_no,@Nuser_mkey,@n_department,@nstatus_flag2,@remarks,               
        CASE WHEN (@cuserid IS NULL) THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END AS @cuserid,
    @u_datetime,@nstatus_flag,@delete_flag,     
        CASE WHEN (@cdept_id IS NULL) THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END AS @cdept_id,
    @inv_hdr_mkey,@No_Of_Days,
     @Approved_Amount,@Chq_No,@Chq_dated,
     @Chq_Bank,@Chq_Amount,@Vendor_MKey,@Vendor_Comp_Mkey,@Project_Mkey,@Program_mkey,@Payment_MKey,@Due_Date  
    ,@Updated_Remarks,@Updated_Bill_no,@Updated_Bill_Date,@Updated_Bill_Amt,@Party_Name,
    @Acc_mkey,@TotalDeductions,@Broker_Mkey,@Customer_Mkey,@Payable_Amt,@Balance_Amt)
```

but getting error as

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Remove "AS"** from your query, as you are going to insert in table, so it is no more required.

```
 CASE WHEN (@cuserid IS NULL) THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END
```

Comment: getting error as `Error converting data type varchar to numeric.`

Comment: Seems one of your column/parameter value type is string and you are going to insert in 'Integer' type column

Comment: my `cuserid ` column is numeric

Comment: So you can't store 'YES/NO' in that column

Comment: You have to store any integer value in that column 0/1 Or other value as per your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand this correctly, you are using the values of declared variables in `VALUES`. If you do some calculations there, you should not name this.

```
AS @cuserid
```

Anyway: You are not allowed to name any expression like this!

You must distinguish between

- Use a variable's value and
- give an alias to an expression

In `VALUES` you give just a list of values:

```
VALUES(@var1,@var2,@var3+5)
```

Will use the value of `@var1` and `@var2` and will do some calculation with `var3`. **You do not need any alias here**

### UPDATE

You might consider to do this logic in the place where you set a value to your variable `@cuserid`. In this case you could use this variable within `VALUES` wihtout bothering about being `NULL` or not...

Comment: u r right, so i did this `CASE WHEN (@cuserid IS NULL) THEN 0 ELSE @cuserid END,`

Comment: but it always going as `0` even the CUser_ID is their

Comment: @stack whatever value you have in `@cuserid ` it will be used in your statement. Are sure, that the code, where you set this value, is correct?

Answer (score 0):

As the error suggests, the problem has nothing to do with `CASE` and everything to do with `AS`.  So, remove the `AS`:

```
 values (@inv_trl_mkey, @entry_sr_no, @Nuser_mkey, @n_department, @nstatus_flag2 ,@remarks,               
    (CASE WHEN (@cuserid IS NULL) THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END),
     @u_datetime,@nstatus_flag,@delete_flag,     
    (CASE WHEN (@cdept_id IS NULL) THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END),
    . . .
```

It doesn't make sense to name the value of expressions in the `VALUES()` clause.

Comment: i am using this in stored procedures. that's why adding like this. now getting error as `Error converting data type varchar to numeric.` the datatype of `CUser_ID` is `numeric`

Comment: You can use 0 or 1 instead of 'Yes' or 'N' if feasible to you because it supports in all varchar,float,numeric etc.

Answer (score 0):

Insert into inward_doc_tracking_trl 
    (Mkey,Entry_Sr_No,N_UserMkey,N_Department,CStatus_Flag,Remarks,
    CUser_Id,
    U_Datetime,NStatus_Flag,Delete_Flag, 
    CDept_Id,
    Ref_Mkey,No_Of_Days,Approved_Amount,Chq_No,Chq_dated,Chq_Bank,Chq_Amount,
    Vendor_MKey,Vendor_Comp_Mkey,Project_Mkey,Program_mkey,Payment_MKey,Due_Date,Updated_Remarks,Updated_Bill_no,
    Updated_Bill_Date,Updated_Bill_Amt,Party_Name,Acc_mkey,
    TotalDeductions,Broker_Mkey,Customer_Mkey,Payable_Amt,Balance_Amt)
     Select (@inv_trl_mkey,@entry_sr_no,@Nuser_mkey,@n_department,@nstatus_flag2,@remarks,
        CASE WHEN (@cuserid IS NULL) THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END AS cuserid,
    @u_datetime,@nstatus_flag,@delete_flag,
        CASE WHEN (@cdept_id IS NULL) THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END AS cdept_id,
    @inv_hdr_mkey,@No_Of_Days,
     @Approved_Amount,@Chq_No,@Chq_dated,
     @Chq_Bank,@Chq_Amount,@Vendor_MKey,@Vendor_Comp_Mkey,@Project_Mkey,@Program_mkey,@Payment_MKey,@Due_Date
    ,@Updated_Remarks,@Updated_Bill_no,@Updated_Bill_Date,@Updated_Bill_Amt,@Party_Name,
    @Acc_mkey,@TotalDeductions,@Broker_Mkey,@Customer_Mkey,@Payable_Amt,@Balance_Amt)  strong text

Answer (score 0):

Your statement is right just do not use **AS** with case if you need to use **AS** Than use blocks inside the case statement as said by **Abihabi87** . And one most important thing is you can not save varchar data inside column when column data type is numeric. For that you need to change datatype of column or save numeric value inside column. for example your using 'Yes/No' rather than you can use '0/1'.